# Mocha Tests, Angular app getting 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$browser.state()')

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js

When running my mocha tests, they were working just fine, but now I am getting... 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$browser.state()') for quite a few (but not all) of them. Any ideas where this is coming from? Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you upgrade angular recently? Make sure angular.mocks is your angular's version compatible.

Comment: Just made sure in bower.json to have Angular and AngularMocks at v1.3.0 and it seems to work now. Thanks PSL and SharkAlley!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem and PSL's suggestion fixed it. You can get the latest version (at time of writing) here:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-mocks.js